# Can I still cook this white king hot cake without using any eggs?

Tags: substitutions, eggs, pancakes

So I have a hotcake mix in a box, White King Hotcake Creamy Classic, but I ran out of eggs.

It's 1:10 AM here in the Philippines and there are no stores open so I'm asking if I can still cook this Hotcake without eggs.

Comment: Probably not. Can you include the full recipe?

Comment: https://www.bigbag.com.ph/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/White-King-Hotcake-Mix-Creamy-Classic-Yummy-and-Fluffy-400g.png this is the picture XD

Answer (score 3):

Generally pancake mixes that require eggs use them as a binder, so if you try to cook them without eggs, they may not hold together.  You can decrease the liquid, but then you'll end up with something tough and probably not what you want.  You may want to have a look at suggestions in answers to [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21427/what-can-i-substitute-for-eggs-in-a-pancake-recipe).