# Vegan substitutes for eggs in baking

Tags: baking, eggs, vegan

What can I use instead of eggs for baking, ie, I need very close vegan alternatives.

Comment: What are you actually baking?  There are many alternatives, but all may not be suitable for all recipes.

Comment: And we already have a list of questions about egg substitutes, vegan and otherwise. While I applaud your initiative, as it’s phrased both the question and the answer are probably too generic for the hugely different kinds of recipes and uses of eggs in baking.

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/with-what-can-i-replace-eggs https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21427/what-can-i-substitute-for-eggs-in-a-pancake-recipe https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-can-i-substitute-for-eggs-in-cookie-recipes https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14025/are-there-any-vegetarian-friendly-egg-substitutes-that-can-be-used-in-cakes

Answer (score 0):

1. Crushed Bananas

This is a very good alternative to eggs, with the only disadvantage being the fact that the finished product will have a slight banana flavor. Use 65g of crushed bananas to replace each egg.

2. Applesauce

Ensure you use unsweetened applesauce though. Also, the measurement is about 65g per egg.

3. Vinegar and baking soda

This combo works best for baked foods that are meant to be light and airy. All you need to do is mix 1 teaspoon of baking soda and 1 tablespoon of vinegar to replace one egg.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just misleading as it currently stands. All of these suggestions have very different properties from eggs. Sure, many recipes may come out nicely if you replace the eggs with those things, but then you haven't really _substituted_ the eggs, rather removed them (and the role they played) entirely, and added something completely different instead. If you explain for which dishes you had success – fine. But trying to treat them as generic egg substitutes is just bound to lead to dissappointments.